# Regex escape put "\\" after astreik instead of before asterik

Tags: c#, regex

I need help to remove "\" before asterik and put it after asterik as explained in below examples -

```
string str = "*10.18).xlsx"; //Other Inputs - *.18).xlsx, *.10.18).xlsx, *(23.10.18).xlsx
string reg = "id:" + Regex.Replace(str, @"[][+&|!(){}^""~*?: \\/-]", "\\$&");

Current Output :
reg = id:\\*10.18\\).xlsx
Required Output :
reg = id:*\\10.18\\).xlsx

More example :
Input - id:*(23.10.18).xlsx
Required Output - id:*\\(23.10.18\\).xlsx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an match evaluator with a bit modified regex:

```
var strs = new List<string> { "*10.18).xlsx", "*(23.10.18).xlsx" };
var block = @"[][+&|!(){}^""~?: \\/-]";
var rx = new Regex($@"(\*)({block}?)|{block}");
foreach (var str in strs) {
    string reg = "id:" + rx.Replace(str, m =>
        m.Groups[1].Success ? $"*\\{m.Groups[2].Value}" : $"\\{m.Value}");
    Console.WriteLine(reg);
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/5qNXaS). Output: `id:*\10.18\).xlsx` (for `*10.18).xlsx`) and `id:*\(23.10.18\).xlsx` (for `*(23.10.18).xlsx`).

The pattern will match

- `(\*)([][+&|!(){}^""~?: \\/-]?)` - an asterisk captured into Group 1 and any of the chars in the block, 1 or 0 times (optionally)
- `|` - or
- `[][+&|!(){}^""~?: \\/-]` - a character class matching `]`, `[`, `+`, `&`, `|`, `!`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `^`, `"`, `~`, `?`, `:`,  , `\`, `/` and `-`

If Group 1 matched the match is replaced with `*\` + Group 2 value, else, the backslash is prepended before the matched char.